# How can I convert a message (str) to a message's ID for discord (int)?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
bot=discord.Client()

@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    idbot = 835947059721797702
    if ctx.author.id == idbot:
        channelsnipe = bot.get_channel(825523364844142601)
        messageid = ctx.content
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2) # Give time for reaction to update on cache
        reaction = messageid.reactions[0] # Get first reaction of a message
        emoji = reaction.emoji
        await messageid.add_reaction(emoji)
```

I'm trying to take the message from the user (idbot) and use it as an ID for add a reaction for the ID's message. But when I try this code, I have this error :     `reaction = messageid.reactions[0] # Get first reaction of a message     AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'reactions'`

Comment: What does the message look like? Just the ID, or also something else?

Comment: the message is the id (str) ==> ```849572257135460392```

Answer (score 0):

First, to avoid confusion with the naming, the parameter to [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) is a [`Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message) object that is usually called `message`, not `ctx`.

There are a few relevant properties of a `Message` object. The value of `message.content` is the string content of the message, `message.id` is the message id, and `message.reactions` is the list of [`Reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#reaction) objects.

If you need to look the message up by its ID as supplied in the user message then you will need to do

```
message_id = int(message.content)
```

which is just usual Python so far and then look the message up using that ID, possibly by calling [`fetch_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message) on the relevant channel. If the message from the user is in the same channel as the message you want to access then you can do

```
target_message = await message.channel.fetch_message(message_id)
```

You then have a `Message` object as per above.

Comment: I dont wanna get the id of the message, the message is the id. For exemple the message is always something like ```849572257135460392```

Comment: Updated my answer to cover that situation

Answer (score 0):

If your message **only** contains the `id` of the message you want to get, then retrive the id via

```
messageid = int(ctx.content)
```

Afterwards you can use [`await channel.fetch_message(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message) to get the message. This however only works, when you know in which channel the message you want to get is in. If the message is in `channelsnipe`, get the message via

```
message = await channelsnipe.fetch_message(messageid)
```

And get first reaction

```
reaction = message.reactions[0]
```

---

bot=discord.Client()

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    idbot = 835947059721797702
    if ctx.author.id == idbot:
        channelsnipe = bot.get_channel(825523364844142601)
        messageid = int(ctx.content) 
        message = await channelsnipe.fetch_message(messageid)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2) # Give time for reaction to update on cache
        reaction = message.reactions[0] # Get first reaction of a message
        emoji = reaction.emoji
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```